# Find identical groups in python data frames pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find the identical orders in my dataframe, that looks similar to this -

```
Order_ID |SKU |Qty |

123 | A | 1 |

123 | B | 2 |

345 | A | 1 |

345 | B | 2 |

678 | A | 1 |

678 | C | 3 |
```

There can be multiple SKUs in an order, i.e., 1 order can have multiple rows.
So the order_ID that contains the exact SKU and qty are identical. Here 123 and 345.
I need the orders that are identical along with SKUs and quantities.

How can I achieve that in pandas dataframe using grouping?

Sample Output would be something like -

```
Order_ID     |   SKU    | Qty        |Unique_Orders
[123] , [345]| [A],[B]  | [1],[2]    |2
[678]        | [A],[C]  | [1],[3]    |1
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: there are many ways to find such groups, but it depends what you want to do with them. Any desired output?  For example, you could sum the `qty`, count rows, count distinct sku, etc.

Comment: If you just want what are unique order_ids you can just list them usiing 
df['order_id'].unique(), but agaiin it depends once you list those unique order_ids as said by @PierreD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Based on an update in the question, here is an updated answer, without any  Python-level loops:

```py
skuqty = df.groupby('Order_ID')[['SKU', 'Qty']].agg(tuple).reset_index()
skuqty.groupby(['SKU', 'Qty'])['Order_ID'].unique().reset_index()
```

Which gives:

```
      SKU     Qty    Order_ID
0  (A, B)  (1, 2)  [123, 345]
1  (A, C)  (1, 3)       [678]
```

Or, if you want to match your specifications exactly, you can further do:

```py
z = skuqty.groupby(['SKU', 'Qty'])['Order_ID'].unique().reset_index()
z = z.assign(SKU=z['SKU'].apply(list)).assign(Qty=z['Qty'].apply(list)).assign(Unique_Orders=z['Order_ID'].apply(len))
z = z[['Order_ID', 'SKU', 'Qty', 'Unique_Orders']]
```

Which gives:

```py
>>> z
     Order_Id     SKU     Qty  Unique_Orders
0  [123, 345]  [A, B]  [1, 2]              2
1       [678]  [A, C]  [1, 3]              1
```

**Speed**

This is relatively fast:

```py
n = 1_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Order_ID': np.random.randint(0, 999, n),
    'SKU': np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), n),
    'Qty': np.random.randint(1, 100, n),
})

%timeit proc(df)  # which is the (first) code above
# 405 ms ± 407 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Original answer**

It depends what you want to do with the groups. Here is an example that sums the `Qty`:

```py
df.groupby('Order_ID')['Qty'].sum()
```

Gives:

```
Order_ID
123    3
345    3
678    4
Name: Qty, dtype: int64
```

Or, if you want to simultaneously see the `Qty` total and the distinct `SKU`:

```py
>>> df.groupby('Order_ID').agg({'Qty':sum, 'SKU':'unique'})
          Qty     SKU
Order_ID             
123         3  [A, B]
345         3  [A, B]
678         4  [A, C]
```

Finally, there is one that gives you a `dict` of `{SKU: Qty}` for each `Order_ID`:

```py
>>> df.groupby('Order_ID').apply(lambda g: dict(g[['SKU', 'Qty']].values))
Order_ID
123    {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
345    {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
678    {'A': 1, 'C': 3}
```

Comment: Thank you, Pierre! You have been super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `groupby` + `unique` to get the unique orders per `SKU` and `Qty`

```
df.groupby(['SKU', 'Qty'])['Order_ID'].unique()
```

If you also want to `count` the number of `unique` order then we can additionally use `nunique`

```
df.groupby(['SKU', 'Qty'])['Order_ID'].agg(['unique', 'nunique'])
```

---

```
                  unique  nunique
SKU Qty                          
A   1    [123, 345, 678]        3
B   2         [123, 345]        2
C   3              [678]        1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['SKU', 'Qty'])['Order_ID'].apply(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```
x = df.groupby("Order_ID")[["SKU", "Qty"]].apply(
    lambda x: frozenset(zip(x.SKU, x.Qty))
)

df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "Order_ID": v.to_list(),
            "SKU": [sku for sku, _ in k],
            "Qty": [qty for _, qty in k],
            "Unique_Orders": len(v),
        }
        for k, v in x.index.groupby(x).items()
    ]
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
     Order_ID     SKU     Qty  Unique_Orders
0  [123, 345]  [A, B]  [1, 2]              2
1       [678]  [C, A]  [3, 1]              1
```

Comment: FYI, the use of explicit Python loops makes this slow for large DataFrames.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use group in this case. Just use the duplicated() function in pandas.

```
df.duplicated()
```

This will return a boolean series with the first duplicated value showed as True and the others similar value followed the first one to be False.

So if you want to retrieve the duplicated ID, just follow normal pandas conditions.

```
df['Order_ID'].loc[df.duplicated()].values.unique()
```

Assuming the Order_ID is a column in the DataFrame and the default id columns still exist.

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'unique'

Comment: @KrishangiGoswami my bad, just drop the unique(). try this: df['Order_ID'].loc[df.duplicated()].values.tolist()